# jQuery multi select drop down and SharePoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I'm hoping I could get some help with multiple drop down selection.  I have a SharePoint jQuery form that I created and I am trying to populate the multiple selection drop down with data.  The data in the column is comma delimited (ex: `Contract A, Contract B`).

Please take a look on [my SharePoint site](http://issharepoint.com/EE/Site%20Pages/DeliverWebpart.aspx). It's better to show to understand.  As you will see, the "Contracts" column is the last column and when you click edit, the "Contract" multiple selection element does not populate.

Comment: I'm getting an error about documentsGetElementsByName is undefined.  What code have you written to try to make this work?

Comment: I created this function "getContractValue()".  I commented out the calling function because it would give me the same value in "Contract" box no matter what 'Performer' is selected.  'Contract' and 'Performer POCs' are rendered based on 'Performer'. Cascading dropdown.

Comment: If you right click and view source in ie8, you should be able to see all the jquery code.